# How to get data from 2 parent tables that are linked via a intermediary table

Tags: mysql, node.js

I have the following tables like below:

```
Table - mytags

| tag_id | tag_name |
|    1   |   home   |
|    2   |   work   |

TABLE - mytasks

| task_id |     task_name     |
|    14   | do my the dishes  |
|    12   | Make presentation |

TABLE - mytasks_mytags

| mytag_id | mytask_id |
|     1    |    14     |
|     2    |    14     |
```

What i would like to get is the task_id , task_name and lastly mytags.tag_name the task_id is associated with , i beleive i will need a query that runs through all 3 tables , but i am not quite sure how to go about building this mysql query, can someone please assist me.

So what i would like is something like:

```
| task_id |     task_name     | tag_name
|    14   | do my the dishes  |   home , work
|    12   | Make presentation |    null
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With mysql you could use a inner join and group_concat group by task_id

```
    select  a.task_id, a.task_name, group_concat(b.tag_name ) tag_name
    from mytasks_mytags c 
    inner join mytasks a on c.mytask_id = a. task_id
    left  join mytags b on b.tag_id = c.mytag_id 
    group by  a.task_id, a.task_name
```

Comment: what is this `a` and `b` etc ?

Comment: are table alias  .. is a way for refer to table name  without repeat the table name

Comment: oh i see !! thanks , just to verify , so when your saying `from mytasks_mytags c` you're setting c as the alias for mytasks_mytags ?

Comment: exactly  ..  c became the name of the table  mytasks_mytags

Comment: last question , why are you using `group by  a.task_id, a.task_name` and not just `group by  a.task_id` ? just curious :)

Comment: Just copied  the column non involved in aggregation function  ...  (in this case is correct use only task_id  )

Comment: Thank you and thanks a ton for the answer , it was so knowledgeably and i leaned alot about SQL from your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
SELECT 
    task_id, taskname, GROUP_CONCAT(tag_name)
FROM
    (SELECT 
        a.task_id, a.taskname, c.tag_name
    FROM
        my_tasks a
    LEFT JOIN mytasks_mytags b ON a.task_id = b.mytasks_id
    LEFT JOIN my_tags c ON b.mytag_id = c.tag_id) a
GROUP BY task_id
ORDER BY task_id DESC;
```

Comment: what is this `a` and `b` etc ?